# How to append textbox value to another textbox

Tags: jquery

Here i'm new to jquery please help me how can i assign textbox value to another tex Like

```
 <b>Enter Some Text</b>   <input type="text" id="TxtHelp" /><br />
        <button id="HelloModal" class="btn">ModalPop</button>
```

When i Enter Text in textbox & click on button the Span showing value but why texbox not showing

```
    <span id="Span1"></span><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JanMic" /><b>hhh</b>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#HelloModal').click(function () {
        var txt = $('#TxtHelp').val();
        $('#Span1').append(txt); //Its showing
        $('#JanMic').append(txt);  //Its not showing
    })
```

Comment: `$('#Span1').text(txt); $('#JanMic').val(txt);`, for a span element use, `.text()` and for an input element use `.val()`

Comment: Thank u soo much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `append()` to [val()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp) to change the value of the input:

```js
$('#HelloModal').click(function () {
     var txt = $('#TxtHelp').val();
     $('#Span1').append(txt);
     $('#JanMic').val(txt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Enter Some Text</b>   <input type="text" id="TxtHelp" /><br />
<button id="HelloModal" class="btn">ModalPop</button>

 <span id="Span1"></span><br />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="JanMic"><b>hhh</b>
```

Comment: Glad to help you